# Raspberry.local connection problem (routing)

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, ethernet

In the last 10 days I've been researching a lot about networks on Linux, more specifically, on Raspberry.
After coming to the conclusion that I will not be able to solve it myself, I come to this forum to try to find the solution, or else, the right way to go.

Using > Raspberry Pi 3

I'm using Ethernet connection (eth0) with Router and P2P with notebook sometimes.

I set up my Raspberry to recognize raspberry.local and use it to login in SSH.
So, what the problem:
The raspberry.local dont work when I plug the Raspi direct on notebook.. I have it in my connection:

```
RPi <--eth0--> Router (IP RPi: 192.168.0.40 and raspberry.local work) Router is the dhcp
RPi <--eth0--> notebook (IP RPi: 169.254.5.95 and raspberry.local dont work)
```

My configs:

```
$ route -n   (RPi <--eth0--> Router)
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0


$ cat /etc/networks
default         0.0.0.0
loopback        127.0.0.0
link-local      169.254.0.0


$ ifconfig   (RPi <--eth0--> Router)
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:d9:4c:3b
          inet addr:192.168.0.40  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::27c8:5163:48b2:87eb/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2804:14d:8a81:1132:8caa:976b:e8bf:3015/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11785 errors:0 dropped:5 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11634 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5789126 (5.5 MiB)  TX bytes:10058686 (9.5 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4943 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4943 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:9649934 (9.2 MiB)  TX bytes:9649934 (9.2 MiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:8c:19:4e
          inet6 addr: fe80::6653:f75d:e2a3:dd39/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)


$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0-raspbian inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

How or what I need do to route the link-local (RPi <-eth0-> notebook) to raspberry.local?
If I use 169.254.5.95 to login in SSH, it work, but this IP change if I use in other computer ou with other RPi.. 
So, I need work with Router(dhcp) and without router (direct eth) and all able to route to hostname raspberry.local
I need help!

Maybe I need create a virtual eth >(eth1?) with static ip routing to 127.0.0.1 and route the 169.254.0.0 to this virtual interface? If it's correct, how do it?

Thank a lot!

Comment: It would work better if you didn't fiddle with the files. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
PS `169.` is a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) - it unclear what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: It may be that the RPi is not configuring `avahi` when there is a link-local address... when connected in link-local, what is the output, on the RPi, of `sudo systemctl status avahi-daemon`